# php laravel regex query for fetching a part of subtitle from database server

Tags: php, regex, database, laravel

I have a subtitle-column in server database.user can search a word like "hello" and should bring the sentences which have this word and the time of subtitles.[such this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sfLo.jpg)
Which query should I use to get the subtitle and its time  in php laravel,the same as [quodb.com](http://www.quodb.com) website

Comment: To answer this we need a little bit more information about either the the models or the database.

Comment: in this image my vedio table which contain subtitle_content https://i.imgsafe.org/1407138e4d.png

Answer (score 1):

This should return the search result. If you want to return multiple results you would need to switch the `first()` to `get()` and iterate through the `$videos` likewise, instead of returning the `$subtitle`, you would probably want to store it in an array or collection and return all the results at the end.

```
public function search($search_param)
{
    $video = Video::where('subtitle_content', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_param.'%')->first();

    $subtitles = explode("-->", $video->subtitle_content);

    foreach($subtitles as $subtitle) {
         if (strpos($subtitle, $search_param) !== false) {
             return $subtitle;
         }
    }

    return 'no results found';
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i need return just  the sentence with its time not the record
,
like search in this site:
http://www.quodb.com/

Comment: I've edited my post but I'm not sure I don't see a time in your tables.

Comment: my subtitle_content contain  records of srt file : 
1
00:02:17,440 --> 00:02:20,375
Senator, we're making
our final approach into Coruscant.

2
00:02:20,476 --> 00:02:22,501
Very good, Lieutenant.


---------------------------
i want return just sentence for ex if i searched good will return :
00:02:20,476 --> 00:02:22,501
Very good, Lieutenant.

Comment: No, the code will return every record contain search_param and i want return part of this record that contain search_paran

Comment: I've added a search within the subtitle content which should split the subtitles by lines. This answer will only return the first result.