# Fetch subtitle lines (English and Chinese) from a video table of a server database

Tags: mysql, database, performance, indexing, srt

First of all, my knowledge on database is limited.

I have a video table (in a server database) with a subtitle_content column which is medium text type of English and Chinese. Here is a sample text of the column in the video table , which is actually srt subtitle (Note: the Chinese sentence is the translation of the preceding English. The number of rows of the video table would be something like ten to fifteen thousands, and the column of each row would contains about a hundred lines of text like below.):

1

00:00:02,000 --> 00:00:04,330

13 meters. You should see it.

13米 您应该看到它。

2

00:00:17,682 --> 00:00:19,392

Okay, take her up and over the bow rail.

好吧，将她抬起并越过弓杆。

3

00:00:21,853 --> 00:00:25,193

Mir 2, we're going over the bow. Stay with us.

米尔2，我们过去了。 和我们在一起。

4

00:00:59,224 --> 00:01:01,394

Okay, quiet. We're rolling.

好的，安静 我们正在滚动。

5

00:01:01,851 --> 00:01:05,181

Seeing her coming out of the darkness like a ghost ship...

看到她像幽灵船一样从黑暗中出来...

There is a similar question here
[php laravel regex query for fetching a part of subtitle from database server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38283453/php-laravel-regex-query-for-fetching-a-part-of-subtitle-from-database-server), while my situation is different in that there are two languages in the subtitle_content column of the video table, and the timestamps of the subtitle lines are not needed to return in the search, they are retrieved in other API for video playing.

What I want to implement is to search an English word or phrase, and the database would return the English sentence with this searching parameter, as well as the following Chinese sentence. While if the searching parameter is Chinese, the Chinese sentence with the searching parameter would be returned, with the preceding English sentence.

My questions regarding the design of the database are:

1. Would full text index be applied for the search for optimization, and how for this bilingual situation? (Answer in the similar question doesn't mention this technique.)
2. Would dividing the subtitle_content into English and Chinese and storing them in two columns (each for one language search, full text index would be easily implemented) sound like a direction towards a better solution? But the problem I can think of lies in two ways: first, the expense of creating another column; second, when a match of search is found in one language in one column, getting the corresponding Chinese or English in another column is also an expense.
3. Is mysql is the type of database to get the job done here, or is there a better choice of database?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the same query.

you have 4 columns in your table (id, timeslot ,text_english. text_chinese), and you select the columns you want with the search pattern

> text_english Like '%rolling%"

you can also take a look at [FULLTEXTINDEX](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html)o
Which would allow you to seartch morre complex word phrasing, or even give you an estimate, how gopd it fits.
Schema

```
Schema::create('subtitle', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('time_duration');
    $table->string('text_english');
    $table->string('text_chinese');
});
$faker = \Faker\Factory::create();
```

CODE

```
$faker = \Faker\Factory::create();


DB::insert('insert into subtitle (time_duration, text_english, text_chinese) 
values (?,?,?)', [ "00:00:02,000 --> 00:00:04,330", "13 meters. You should see it.", "13米 您应该看到它。"]);


$users = DB::table('subtitle')
->where('text_english', 'LIKE', '%should%')
->orWhere('text_chinese', 'LIKE', '%should%')
->first();

return $users;
```

you can  run this here https://implode.io/j14COO

Comment: The question is: how to get corresponding translation of text_chinese for the matches when searching English in text_english? (And vice versa)

Comment: The select on the linked gets you the first subtitle **row** that has the searchterm in it, that is that what you want as far as i can see i the row is both english text complete and chines text complete, and time stamp and id. Make a test table with entrys and try the query see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a9637bd3d682571c12fe7f81e0988b4b  this is what your query will do, when you enhace the answer from the link

Comment: Thank you very much, @nbk I think I didn't get my question fully across. Actually, my video table looks like this: video id, videoUrl, subtitle_content . As I understand from your setup, it seems a subtitle table is created to store the subtitle text, am I correct? Now, my question is: would the id of this subtitle table be stored in my subtitle_context column? And where to implement full text index then?

Comment: you wanted to know how to solve this in mysql and laravel.. i added the laravel code for testing to my answer.  so you see how it would work.

Comment: My main interest here is to return the sentences containing search parameter, and the video id, which will be used to get the videoUrl. Where is my video table now?